# Is there a way to push an element of another array to a specific array that's in a 2d array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

Basically I need to do this: take x element of each array in a 2D array and push that to the x element of a different array.

I'm not getting any syntax errors but my program stops running (but console.logs on either side of this line and only the top one logged). Here's my code:

```
for (var i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
          for (var j = 0; j < myArray[i].length; j++) {
            console.log("Hi")
            finishedarray[i].push(myArray[i][j])
            console.log("Hi x2")

          }
        }
```

How should I go about getting around this?

Comment: do you have the arrays as well?

Comment: It will be nice to see a sample of the input and the expected output. That's a good way of clarify your needs.

Answer (score 0):

### FlatMap

What you want to do is called flat mapping. Way to built a `flatMap` functionality is to use `reduce` in combination with spread operator or `Array.concat` like this:

#### Reduce + Spread/Concat

ES2015

```
const myArray = [
   [1, 2, 3],
   [4, 5, 6],
   [7, 8, 9]
];

const finishedArray = myArray
   .reduce((combinedArr, currentArr) => ([...combinedArr, ...currentArr]), []);

console.log(finishedArray); // Prints: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

ES5

```
var myArray = [
   [1, 2, 3],
   [4, 5, 6],
   [7, 8, 9]
];

var finishedArray = myArray
   .reduce(function (combinedArr, currentArr) {
      return combinedArr.concat(currentArr);
   }, []);

console.log(finishedArray); // Prints: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

#### Array.flat

```
var myArray = [
   [1, 2, 3],
   [4, 5, 6],
   [7, 8, 9]
];

var finishedArray = myArray.flat();
console.log(finishedArray); // Prints: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

### Bugfix to your solution

Your code should work with a slight bug fix as well. The problem in your code is that you try to push an entry to `finishedarray[i]` - but you have an empty array and access position `i`, which returns `undefined`. Just push to the array directly:

#### for-Loop

```
for (var i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
   for (var j = 0; j < myArray[i].length; j++) {
      finishedarray.push(myArray[i][j]);  // removed the "[i]" part in front of ".push"
   }
}
```

#### for...of Loop

```
for (var arr of myArray) {
   for (var entry of arr) {
      finishedarray.push(entry);
   } 
}
```

**Edit**: Added Array.flat. Thanks for the comment pointing to that!

Comment: How are you sure the OP wants to flatten the array? Looking at the code, it appears that wants to copy all elements into another 2D array. Anyway, there is no mapping here, and there exists [Array.flat()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat) too.

Comment: Oh indeed, not sure how I could have missed that. I'll update the answer accordingly. And the code looked to me like he wanted to flatten it.